# opening port 7 (echo port) on Linux/Debian

Tags: linux, debian, networking, tcp

I need an echo server on my Linux/Debian for debugging purposes , I realized that there is an assigned port shown in '/etc/services' to do that already and it's port 7 TCP/UDP.

Is it possible to open this port on Linux (Debian)? if not, what are alternatives?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but the linked *question* contains the answer to this one.

Comment: Why the echo service?

Comment: @StephenKitt unfortunately there is no 'inetd.conf' file in '/etc', I guess this file can be found in RH not Debian. there should be a new method to enable this service

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro just learning Linux network programming,simplest client codes can send a string to an echo server and receive it. there should be an echo server to test the client.

Comment: You need to install an `inetd` server of some sort, *e.g.* `openbsd-inetd`; then you’ll have an `/etc/inetd.conf` file.

Comment: @StephenKitt I would prefer `xinetd`

Comment: @Rui I wouldn’t any more, but each to his own :-).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  now I remember xinetd I worked with it years ago! helped a lot thanks

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For setting up a echo service in Debian, you can install `xinetd` with:

```
apt-get install xinetd
```

Than you have to change the `disable` directive to `no` in `/etc/xinetd.d/echo`; or if the file does not exist, create it as shown here:

```
# default: off
# description: An xinetd internal service which echo's characters back to
# clients.
# This is the tcp version.
service echo
{
    disable     = no
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = echo-stream
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    user        = root
    wait        = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service echo
{
    disable     = yes
    type        = INTERNAL
    id      = echo-dgram
    socket_type = dgram
    protocol    = udp
    user        = root
    wait        = yes
}
```

After setting `disable = no`, or creating the file, your restart `xinetd` with:

```
sudo service xinetd restart
```

To test the `echo` TCP service:

```
$nc localhost echo
testing...
testing...
xxxx
xxxx
^C
```

Comment: It’s not a good idea to enable UDP echo...

Comment: @StephenKitt Indeed, it was as an example, however from a security point of view is generally a bad ideia. Edited the answer.